# Best ways to draw geometric shapes given "partial" information

Tags: metapost, metafun

I am trying to draw geometric shapes given only "partial" information.
Let me show you some examples with triangles:

> Construct a triangle ABC such that ∡CAB=75°, d(A,B)=40 and d(C,A)=60.

For this one, I have done it like this:

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  save A, B, C, x ;
  pair A, B, C ;
  path x ;

  A = origin ;
  B = (40, 0) ;
  x = (B-A) rotatedabout(A,75) ;
  C = point 1 of x * 6/4 ;

  draw fullcircle scaled 2abs (A-B) shifted A withcolor lightgray;
  draw A--B--C--cycle;

  dotlabel.bot("A", A) ;
  dotlabel.bot("B", B) ;
  dotlabel.top("C", C) ;
\stopMPpage
```

which produces

[image]

So, well, it works however I am not quite happy neither with how I found the coordinates of `pair C` nor how I have to found the `path x`.

So, I thought I could use circles:

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  save A, B, C, c, x;
  pair A, B, C ;
  path c, x ;

  A = origin ;
  B = (40, 0) ;
  c = fullcircle scaled 120 shifted A ;
  x = (B--A) rotatedabout(A, 75) shortened -100;
  C = c intersectionpoint x ;

  draw c withcolor lightgray;
  draw A--B--C--cycle ;

  dotlabel.bot("A", A) ;
  dotlabel.bot("B", B) ;
  dotlabel.top("C", C) ;
\stopMPpage
```

but this seems even worse.

Another one would be

> Construct a triangle ABC such that d(A,B)=60, ∡BAC=50° and ∡ABC=65°.

```
\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  save A, B, C, x, y ;
  pair A, B, C ;
  path x, y ;

  A = origin ;
  B = (60, 0) ;
  x = (B--A) rotatedabout(A, 50) ;
  y = (B--A) rotatedabout(B, -65) ;
  C = x intersectionpoint y;

  draw fullcircle scaled 2abs (A-B) shifted A withcolor lightgray;
  draw A--B--C--cycle;

  dotlabel.bot("A", A) ;
  dotlabel.bot("B", B) ;
  dotlabel.top("C", C) ;
\stopMPpage
```

which produces

[image]

and, again, I am not satisfied with that. Particularly with `path x` and `path y`: if we change the angles, it would probably does not work any more.

In [the answer to my last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686941/213111), [Thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston) mentioned his useful [Drawing with Metapost](https://ctan.org/pkg/drawing-with-metapost?lang=en) document, but I did not find anything about all of that in it.

Some, my question is: is there better ways to draw that sort of geometric shapes?

Comment: Your first `x` look like a path with one point, is that on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative might be to use the `whatever` construction. MetaPost is good in solving systems of equations. Below I only do the triangles, since I get the feeling that this is your main problem.

```
\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  save A, B, C ;
  pair A, B, C ;

  A = origin ;
  B = (40, 0) ;
  C = (60, 0) rotated 75 ;
  draw A--B--C--cycle ;

  dotlabel.bot("A", A) ;
  dotlabel.bot("B", B) ;
  dotlabel.top("C", C) ;
\stopMPpage

\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  save A, B, C ;
  pair A, B, C ;

  A = origin ;
  B = (60, 0) ;
  C = whatever*dir(50) = B + whatever*dir(180 - 65) ;
  draw A--B--C--cycle;

  dotlabel.bot("A", A) ;
  dotlabel.bot("B", B) ;
  dotlabel.top("C", C) ;
\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

Output:

[image: triangles]

Comment: Oh, thank you, it seems perfect and much better than mines. Can I ask you to explain both lines `C = (60, 0) rotated 75 ;` and `C = whatever*dir(50) = B + whatever*dir(180 - 65) ;` since I have a vague idea, but not very sure, of how it works?

Comment: The first one, `rotated 75` is rotation around the origin 75 degrees. So, maybe `rotatedaround` is a more clean solution there. For the other, the whatever stands for some (any) real number, and it can be different each time. So, we describe the point `C` to be some point in the direction of 50 degrees and also, from `B` seen, something in the direction of `180-65` degrees. That defines `C` uniquely.